# Convert String to "M:S" time format

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime, time

I have a Pandas Dataframe column that contains a string in the format of "60:34" for MINUTES and SECONDS. This is data from a sporting event. I want a time format that is only Minutes and Seconds but I'm having trouble. Below are some things I have tried. 
CODE:

```
final_df['time_on_ice'] = pd.to_datetime(final_df['time_on_ice'], format='%M:%S').dt.time

final_df['time_on_ice'] = final_df['time_on_ice'].astype('datetime64[ns]')

pd.to_datetime(final_df['time_on_ice'], infer_datetime_format=True)
```

ERROR:

> ValueError: time data '60:00' does not match format '%M:%S' (match)
>
> ParserError: hour must be in 0..23: 29:14
>
> ValueError: hour must be in 0..23

Comment: The function only recognizes time from 0-59 minutes, what is why it is giving an error, it expects there to be an hour term if it goes over 59 minutes.

Comment: Does format exist that accepts only Minutes and seconds ?

Comment: Can you give an example output of what you want the '60:34' to look like at the end of this?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve], as well as the entire error message. Speaking of, what do/don't you understand from the error message?

Comment: I understand the error message. I am just looking for a time format that doesn't care about hours and is only 'M:S'. This is for hockey data so most goalies play 60 minutes exactly. I will work on an example later.

Comment: @katardin I want it to look just like that but in time format.